# Pandas append filtered row to another DataFrame

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have 2 pandas data frames `df` and `df_min`. I apply some filters to `df`, which results in a single row of data, and I'd like to append that row to `df_min`. I tried using a loop to traverse `df`, and tried using `loc` to append the row to `df_min`. I keep getting a `Incompatible indexer with DataFrame` ValueError for the line where I use `loc`. I guess I am not using `loc` correctly. What would be the best way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

```
i = 0
for elem in vehicles:
    for state in limit_states:
        a = df[(df.VEHICLE == elem) & (df.LIMIT_STATE == state)]
        df_min.loc[i] = a[(a.RF == np.min(a.RF))].head(1) #results in a single row
        i = i + 1
```

EDIT: I also tried the following instead of `loc`, but got the same error:

```
df_min.ix[i] = a[(a.RF == np.min(a.RF))].head(1)
```

EDIT 2: Tried the following, got a "first argument must be a list-like of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"" error this time.

```
for elem in vehicles:
    for state in limit_states:
        a = df[(df.VEHICLE == elem) & (df.LIMIT_STATE == state)]
        df_min = pd.concat(a[(a.RF == np.min(a.RF))].head(1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably something like this would be helpful:

```
df_min = pd.concat([ df[(df.VEHICLE == elem) & (df.LIMIT_STATE == state)]
                     for elem in vehicles for state in limit_states ])
```

**edit**:

```
xs = [ df[(df.VEHICLE == elem) & (df.LIMIT_STATE == state)]
                     for elem in vehicles for state in limit_states ]
df_min = pd.concat([ a[(a.RF == np.min(a.RF))].head(1) for a in xs ])
```

depending on lists `vehicles` and `limit_states` you probably can also achieve what you are trying to do using `groupby`; something like:

```
fn = lambda a: a[(a.RF == np.min(a.RF))].head(1)
df.groupby( ['VEHICLE', 'LIMIT_STATE'] ).apply( fn )
```

Comment: Thanks! How would I implement the `a[(a.RF == np.min(a.RF))].head(1)` line into this structure? It does a second filtering.